# Crystallized Weapon ability. How quickly can you charge you melee weapon/s?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Crystallized Weapon ability. How quickly can you charge you melee weapon/s?

It was never specified weather it is a full, standard, move, swift or fee action go do so. Also what if you have multiple attacks from higher levels or Two Weapon Fighting? Do you charge every weapon you are wielding? What if you're using unarmed, do you charge your whole body or every limb? Can you quickly charge your melee weapon/s as you attack if you have multiple attacks?

Answer (score 1):

Crystallized weapon, an Aegis customization, treats all weapons used while the customization is active as Deep Crystal. The rules for charging a [Deep Crystal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/psionic-special-materials#TOC-Crystal-Deep) weapon are provided in the page for that material. Charging a weapon with power points is a free action.

You only charge one weapon per action for 2 power points, but it's a free action so you can charge before every attack if you choose. Notably, if you miss in melee, the charge on the weapon is not expended (you don't have to charge it again, it keeps the charge for one minute or until a hit is scored).

Comment: So would that technically mean your whole body is charge if you used unarmed combat since since unarmed combat encompasses some  if not you whole body for combat? (Punch- Arms , Kick - Legs, Head but- head and tackle, overrun, charge - whole body)

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Well, unarmed strikes are "always considered a light weapon", and the ability says your "weapon is treated as if made from deep crystal." Ergo, fists count as masterwork and can be charged like deep crystal. Do note that this wouldn't give you extra bonuses on things like Overrun and such, just to Unarmed Strike (the weapon).

Comment: Makes sense, so limbs (kick - punch) are the only ones counted and the head is covered by the Aegis Ram ability.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Pretty much. Do note that the Ram ability is *not* a weapon, and thus *cannot* be charged as a deep crystal weapon. It's a supernatural ability that happens to allow an attack in specific circumstances.

Comment: Yes I know about Ram, I just added it there since it has a similar scaling damage ability with use of PP.